How to enable the compiler to optimise a dispatch table
Consider the following code that generically creates a dispatch table with a maximum size and then dispatches based on a runtime index:
#include <utility>

template <class D, std::size_t... I> auto dispatch(std::size_t i, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    using F = decltype(&D::template dispatch<0>);
    static constexpr F table[sizeof...(I)] = {&D::template dispatch<I>...};
    return table[i]();
}
template <class D, std::size_t MAX_SIZE> auto dispatch(std::size_t i) {
    return dispatch<D>(i, std::make_index_sequence<MAX_SIZE>());
}

struct Dispatcher {
    template <std::size_t I> static auto dispatch() {
        return 42;
    }
};

auto foo(std::size_t i) {
    constexpr std::size_t MAX_SIZE = 10;
    if (i < MAX_SIZE) {
        return dispatch<Dispatcher, MAX_SIZE>(i);
    }
    return 0;
}

Both GCC 14.1 and Clang 18.1 with optimization level -O3 will generate code for 10 identical functions and then dispatch dynamically. Is there a way I can make GCC or Clang recognize that these functions are identical and optimize the dynamic dispatch away? For my use case the dispatch function is part of a library that might be called in different ways and I would like the compiler to optimize the dispatch if all the functions in the table are identical and only generate the table and dispatch if they are not identical.
Link to Compiler Explorer

Looking at this answer I found this libstdc++ commit. It looks like GCC is bad at optimizing dispatch tables and therefore the standard library contains a special case for optimizing std::visit for std::variants with a small number of alternatives.
